# Why am I getting an int and not a double back when the starting value is a double?

Tags: c++

I am wondering if anyone could help me understand why I am getting an int here and not a double? My guess is it probably due to the fact the decimal part is just .00 but how can I make sure it writes it anyway.
Thanks!

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

  // initalize variables

  string dataLine;

  string stationName;
  string substringMaxTemp;
  string substringLowTemp;
  int positionMaxTemp;
  int positionLowTemp;
  double maxTemp = 0.0;
  double minTemp = 99.9;
  int positionStationName = 0;

  ifstream inputFile;

  // open the input file (program expects the file to be in the same directory
  // as the program)
  inputFile.open("reduced_columns(2).txt");
  // check if the file is successfully opened
  if (!inputFile) {
    cout << "Error opening file" << endl;
    return 1;
  } else {
    cout << "Input file opened successfully." << '\n' << endl;
  }

  getline(inputFile, dataLine);
  // find position of temps in the array
  positionMaxTemp = dataLine.find("TMAX");
  positionLowTemp = dataLine.find("TMIN");
  positionStationName = dataLine.find("STATION");

  // loop
  while (!inputFile.eof()) {
    getline(inputFile, dataLine);
    // needed to avoid out of range error (last line empty)
    if (dataLine.length() == 0) {
      break;
    }

    // loop for maxTemp
    double currentMax = stod(dataLine.substr(positionMaxTemp, 5));
    string stationName = dataLine.substr(positionStationName, 40);

    if (currentMax > maxTemp) {
      maxTemp = currentMax;
    }

    // loop for minTemp
    double currentLow = stod(dataLine.substr(positionLowTemp, 5));
    
    if (currentLow < minTemp) {
      minTemp = currentLow;
    }
  }

  inputFile.close();
  inputFile.open("reduced_columns(2).txt");
  getline(inputFile, dataLine);

  while (!inputFile.eof()) {
    getline(inputFile, dataLine);
    // needed to avoid out of range error (last line empty)
    if (dataLine.length() == 0) {
      break;
    }

    // loop for maxTemp
    double currentMax = stod(dataLine.substr(positionMaxTemp, 5));
    string stationName = dataLine.substr(positionStationName, 40);

    if (currentMax == maxTemp) {
      cout << stationName << "recorded a maximum temperature of " << maxTemp<< endl;
    }

    // loop for minTemp
    double currentLow = stod(dataLine.substr(positionLowTemp, 5));
    if (currentLow == minTemp) {
      cout << stationName << "recorded a minimum temperature of " << minTemp<< endl;
    }
  }

  cout << endl << "The lowest tempers in december 2023 was " << minTemp << endl;
  cout << "The highest temp in december 2023 was " << maxTemp << endl;

  // close file
  inputFile.close();
  return 0;
}type here
```

Hi! I am wondering if anyone could help me understand why I am getting an int here and not a double? My guess is it probably due to the fact the decimal part is just .00 but how can I make sure it writes it anyway.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you really need all of this code to test how `double` works with `std::cout`?  A simple two or three-line `main` program could have been written: `#include <iostream> int main() { double d = 1.0; std::cout << d; }`.  Given that program, the next question should have been "how do I print the decimal portion of the double?", and there are plenty of answers to that question.

Comment: No, the assignment I had was about something else. I did try to set precision to 2 but it would still print without the decimal. In the output solution given by the teacher, it shows the .00 so I am trying to get it identical. I could just add ".00" during my cout, but I just wanted to make sure I was not missing something else.

Comment: *My guess is it probably due to the fact the decimal part is just .00 **but how can I make sure it writes it anyway**.* @PaulMcKenzie me thinks that while the OP runs in circles, the OP still contains the question. What do you think?

Comment: The code can be reduced a lot to be "minimal" [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @user12002570 probably lol, I realize its an eye sore. I'm just starting and the teacher's example looked similar so I tried to use the things he showed us.

Comment: @MarMar90 -- If a programmer is not familiar with how to do <x>, the programmer writes a small program that attempts to do <x>.  Once they learn how to do <x>, they apply that to the larger program.

Comment: Rolled back the l;ast edit because the question no longer made any sense.

Comment: Note that the phrase "[mre]" has the word "minimal" not "missing". Many questions should have *some* code, just a lot less than this one.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a minimal example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    double d = 1.0;

    std::cout << d << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << d << std::endl;
}
```

The output:

```
1
1.00
```

As suspected, the only difference is specifying the precision to print the `double` value with.

Comment: Thanks! with fixed, it worked. Would mind explaining to me why just setprecision would not work?

Comment: It doesn't work because [setprecision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) is not designed to do what you were asking it to do.  *If* decimals were printed, *then*, `std::setprecision` would come into play.  The problem is that decimal printing is "turned off" by default when the decimal portion is 0.  [Here is the documentation for std::fixed](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed).

Comment: The meaning of "precision" changes when you use "fixed".  With "fixed", precision is the number of digits after the decimal point.  Without it, precision is the maximum number of significant digits printed.

Comment: *"the only difference is specifying the precision"* -- That's not the **only** difference. You also added `std::fixed`.